# Split rows and columns in SQL server and insert into temporary table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have data in one column of a particular table which has the following format:

```
item1 char(1) value1 char(1) value2 char(0) item2 char(1) value3 char(1) value4 char(0)
```

Note:

`char(0)` and `char(1)` and the characters themselves. There is also no spaces.

What I need to do is to split the column of the original table:

1. first into rows by splitting using `char(0)`
2. then for each row in (1) split again using `char(1)`

The result should be a table with 2 colums and x rows:

```
column1 column2 colum3
----------------------
item1   value1  value2
item2   value3  value4
```

I'm writing a CLR function to split the data:

```
public partial class Functions
{
    public static IEnumerable SplitData(SqlString value)
    {
        string[] rows = value.Value.Split('\n');

        for (int i = 0, n = rows.Length; i < n; i++)
        {

        }

        return rows;
    }
}
```

Each row will contain text, for example:

```
item char(1) value1 char(1) value2
```

The second step is to split each row (which is easy).

But how can the function return the table above so that it can be processed further in SQL server?

Comment: Please add test data and expected results

Comment: Are you familiar with pivto/unpivot? I found it on MSSQL, I can't test it now :-(, here is the link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Is the temptable fixed? Or can it differ?

Comment: @Jaques it's a memory table local to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test table and data:

```
DECLARE @t table(id int identity(1,1), col1 varchar(max))
insert @t values
('item'+char(1)+ 'value1'+char(1)+'value4'+char(1)+char(0)+ 'item'+char(1)+'value1'+char(1)+ 'value2'+char(1)+char(0)),
('item'+char(1)+ 'value1'+char(1)+'value2'+char(1)+char(0)+ 'item2'+char(1)+'value1'+char(1)+ 'value2'+char(1)+char(0))
```

Query:

```
;WITH SplitByRow as
(
        SELECT id, t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') colx
        FROM (
            SELECT id, x = CAST('<t>' + 
                REPLACE(REPLACE(col1, char(1), '!new row!'), char(0), '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
        FROM @t
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
), SplitByColumn as
(
  SELECT 
    id,
    (row_number() over (order by (select 1))+2)/3 rowx, 
    (row_number() over (order by (select 1))+2)%3 colx,
    t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') value
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, x = CAST('<t>' + 
            REPLACE(colx, '!new row!', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
        FROM SplitByRow
    ) a
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
    WHERE t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') <> ''
)
SELECT 
  id, [0] col1,[1] col2,[2] col3
FROM 
  SplitByColumn 
INTO 
  #temp
PIVOT
    (min([value]) FOR colx
    in([0],[1],[2])  
)AS p
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM #temp

id  col1    col2    col3
1   item    value1  value4
1   item    value1  value2
2   item    value1  value2
2   item2   value1  value2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to create your split function as a clr. In .NET you will have access to much better toolset of stringfunctions with decent performance. Probably better performance than you'll get if you do it in t-sql.